# Flutter user data taking up a lot of space

Tags: flutter, dart

My flutter app user data takes up a lot of space. I'm currently using the following code to save the user data

```
class FileUtil {
 static Future<String> get getFilePath async {
   final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
   return directory.path;
 }

 static Future<File> get getFile async {
   final path = await getFilePath;
   return File('$path/user.txt');
 }

 static Future<File> saveToFile(String data) async {
   final file = await getFile;
   return file.writeAsString(data);
 }

 static Future readFromFile() async {
   try {
     final file = await getFile;
     String fileContents = await file.readAsString();
     log(fileContents);
     return json.decode(fileContents);
   } catch (e) {
     return "";
   }
 }

 String formatData() {
   String formattedString;
   Map x = {};
   x['a'] = a;
   // other variables
   formattedString = json.encode(x);
   return formattedString;
 }

 void saveData() async {
   try {
     await saveToFile(formatData());
     //print('DATA SAVED');
   } catch (e) {
     //print('Could not save data due to: $e');
   }
 }
}
```

Whenever the user interacts with something in the app that needs to be saved, I run `saveData()`. This happens quite often in my app. However, after using the app for a while, the user data can jump to a few hundred MB. I've used a JSON calculator to estimate the space of the `formatData()` output string and it's much less than 1MB. What should I do to minimise user data?

Comment: you could take a look at the directory you save the data in. there might be some information useful to solve your problem. take a look at the actual files in that directory and see what is really being saved to them.

Comment: I have a simple question here, What's the frequency of this function call ? Alternatively you can use `SharedPreferences` instead of saving in _File_. Check [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), and [streaming_shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/streaming_shared_preferences).

Comment: I have had a good experience with `SharedPreferences`. It's really simple and reasonably fast

Comment: I can't really use SharedPreferences as some of the data includes maps and lists. The function is called very often, whenever a user decides to add/remove something to a list, change username, edit settings etc

Comment: Have you considered using NoSQL approach? Like [sembast](https://pub.dev/packages/sembast) or [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)

Comment: Have you actually tried to take a look at what is actually being saved to the files or if there is duplicated data or files? I don't know the cause of your problem, but I something tells me this could help you in debugging your issue

Comment: update: I didn't realise that if I installed the release app as an update to a debug app, the user data stays large. So there was no problem with my handling of user data, just me not realising that I had to clear user data on the device first. Sorry about that :)